# SASS: converting RGB to RGBa

Tags: css, sass

I have set up the colours of my project like so:

```
$blue: rgb(75, 179, 209);
```

Is there any way to use this variable and convert the value into RGBa elsewhere as needed?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

using [rgba instance method](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/Sass/Script/Functions.html#rgba-instance_method)

you can

```
$blue: rgb(75, 179, 209);

body {
    background:rgba($blue, .5);
}
```

can test here: https://sass-lang.com/playground/

Comment: Please update the test link to: https://sass-lang.com/playground/

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a better solution would be to create your own function which you'll call whenever you need it.
Hampton Catlin (the author of Sass) proposes a good solution, which basically goes like this:

```
@function set-opacity ($color) {
    $lightness: lightness($color);
    $trans-value: transparentize($color, $lightness);
        @return $trans-value;
    }
```

So, in essence, you firstly use the Sass function lightness (which is complementary to opacity), and then the Sass function transparentize - which second argument is the result of transparentize.
However, Catlin shows that this needs to be improved - since ligthness() results in percents, but we need values between 0 and 1.
Therefore, we need an additional function that transforms percents to the desired values. It is a simple function, since we simply divide the percents with 100.

```
@function percent-to-number ($val) {
    @return $val / 100;
    }
```

Now, we are ready to go - and the whole block of code goes like this:

```
    @function percent-to-number ($val) {
        @return $val / 100;
    }

    @function set-opacity ($color) {
        $lightness: lightness($color);
        $lightness-number: percent-to-number($lightness);
        $trans-value: transparentize($color, $lightness-number);
            @return $trans-value;
    }
```

So, for example,

```
color: set-opacity(#f00);
```

gives this CSS output:

```
color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
```

Hopefully this helps. It seems too much work, but if you put this function in partials _functions, it will always be helpful. Otherwise, you'll end up writing a variable for each colour you want alpha value.